# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB bluetooth manager

Tags: android, kotlin

> Bluetooth Class for views

```
class BluetoothClass : AppCompatActivity() {


    var mBluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
    lateinit var m_pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>
    var discover_btn: Button? = null
    var deviceHardwareAddress :String?=null
    val REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1
    val deviceList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList(
    val TAG = "BluetoothManager2"
     val bmanager:BluetoothManagerClass=BluetoothManagerClass()
    var btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Button? = null
    var btnONOFF: Button? = null

    var mBTDevices = java.util.ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>()
    var mDeviceListAdapter: BluetoothListAdapter? = null
    var listview_discover: ListView? = null

    var deviceName = String()

    companion object {
        val EXTRA_ADDRESS: String = "Device_address"

    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_access)
        listview_discover = findViewById<View>(R.id.discover_bluetoot_list) as ListView
        discover_btn = findViewById<View>(R.id.discover_button) as Button
        btnONOFF = findViewById(R.id.onoffdiscover_button)
        btnEnableDisable_Discoverable =
            findViewById(R.id.enablediscover_button)
        bmanager.mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

        mBTDevices = java.util.ArrayList()

        select_device_refresh.setOnClickListener { pairedDeviceList()
        }
            btnONOFF!!.setOnClickListener {
                bmanager.enableDisableBT()

                Log.d(this.TAG, "onClick: enabling/disabling bluetooth.")
            }

        }

        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (bmanager.mBluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth has been enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth has been disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    }
                } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth enabling has been canceled",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                }
            }
        }


        fun btnEnableDisable_Discoverable(view: View?) {
            Log.d(
                this.TAG,
                "btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Making device discoverable for 300 seconds."
            )
            bmanager.enalbedisablediscovery()

        }
 @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun checkBTPermissions() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            var permissionCheck =
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION")
                } else {
                    TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < M")
                }
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                permissionCheck += checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION")
            } else {
                TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < M")
            }

            if (permissionCheck != 0) {
                requestPermissions(
                    arrayOf(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
                    ), 1001
                ) //Any number
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(
                this.TAG,
                "checkBTPermissions: No need to check permissions. SDK version < LOLLIPOP."
            )
        }
    }



    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)

    fun btnDiscover(view: View?) {
        Log.d(this.TAG, "btnDiscover: Looking for unpaired devices.")
           bmanager.discovering()
        bmanager.startdiscovering()

    }

    fun pairedDeviceList() {
        m_pairedDevices = bmanager.mBluetoothAdapter!!.bondedDevices
        val list: ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> = ArrayList()

        if (!m_pairedDevices.isEmpty()) {
            for (device: BluetoothDevice in m_pairedDevices) {
                list.add(device)
                Log.i("device", "" + device)
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "no paired bluetooth devices found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();

        }

        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list)
        select_device_list.adapter = adapter
        select_device_list.onItemClickListener =
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
                val device: BluetoothDevice = list[position]
                val address: String = device.name.toString()

                val intent = Intent(this, BluetoothControl::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(BluetoothClass.EXTRA_ADDRESS, address)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
    }
}
```

> Bluetooth manager class for receivers 
>       class BluetoothManagerClass {
>          val device=String
>           var mBluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null``
>           lateinit var m_pairedDevices: Set
>           var discover_btn: Button? = null
>           var deviceHardwareAddress :String?=null
>           val REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1
>           //val deviceList: ArrayList = ArrayList()

```
    val TAG = "BluetoothManager"

    var btnEnableDisable_Discoverable: Button? = null
    var btnONOFF: Button? = null

    var mDeviceListAdapter: BluetoothListAdapter? = null
    var listview_discover: ListView? = null
    private var myApiClass: BluetoothClass =
        BluetoothClass()
    var deviceName = String()

    companion object {
        val EXTRA_ADDRESS: String = "Device_address"
    }
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun discovering() {
        if (this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.isDiscovering) {
            this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.cancelDiscovery()
            Log.d(this.TAG, "btnDiscover: Canceling discovery.")
            //check BT permissions in manifest
            myApiClass.checkBTPermissions()

            this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.startDiscovery()
            val discoverDevicesIntent = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
            myApiClass.registerReceiver(mBroadcastDiscovernewDevice, discoverDevicesIntent)
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    fun startdiscovering(){
        if (!this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.isDiscovering) { //check BT permissions in manifest
            myApiClass.checkBTPermissions()
            this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.startDiscovery()
            val discoverDevicesIntent = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
            myApiClass.registerReceiver(mBroadcastDiscovernewDevice, discoverDevicesIntent)
        }

    }

      fun enalbedisablediscovery(){
          val discoverableIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE)
          discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300)
         myApiClass. startActivity(discoverableIntent)
          val intentFilter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED)
          myApiClass.registerReceiver(mBroadcastDiscoverable, intentFilter)
      }
    fun enableDisableBT() {
        if (this.mBluetoothAdapter == null) {

            Log.d(this.TAG, "enableDisableBT: Does not have BT capabilities.")
        }
        if (!this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            Log.d(this.TAG, "enableDisableBT: enabling BT.")
            val enableBTIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
            myApiClass.startActivity(enableBTIntent)
            val BTIntent = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
            myApiClass.registerReceiver(mBroadcastBluetoothOnOff, BTIntent)
        }
        if (this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.isEnabled) {
            Log.d(this.TAG, "enableDisableBT: disabling BT.")
            this.mBluetoothAdapter!!.disable()
            val BTIntent = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
            myApiClass.registerReceiver(mBroadcastBluetoothOnOff, BTIntent)
        }
    }
    private val mBroadcastBluetoothOnOff: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                val state =
                    intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)
                when (state) {
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF ->
                        Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "onReceive: STATE OFF")
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING OFF"
                    )
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE ON"
                    )
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver1: STATE TURNING ON"
                    )
                }

            }
        }
    }
    val mBroadcastDiscovernewDevice: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        val arrayList = ArrayList<String>()
        var deviceName = String()

        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            Log.d(ContentValues.TAG, "onReceive: ACTION FOUND.")
            if (action == BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND) {
                val device =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                Log.d(
                    ContentValues.TAG,
                    "onReceive: " + device.name + ": " + device.address
                )

                deviceName = device.name
                val deviceHardwareAddress = device.address
                arrayList.add(deviceName)


                var mBTDevices = java.util.ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>()

                mBTDevices = java.util.ArrayList()

                var mDeviceListAdapter: BluetoothListAdapter? = null
                var listview_discover: ListView? = null

                mDeviceListAdapter =
                    BluetoothListAdapter(context, R.layout.device_adapter_view, mBTDevices)
                listview_discover!!.setAdapter(mDeviceListAdapter)
                mBTDevices.add(device)

            }
        }
    }
    val mBroadcastDiscoverable: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            if (action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED) {
                val mode =
                    intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)
                when (mode) {
                    BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Enabled."
                    )
                    BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Able to receive connections."
                    )
                    BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_NONE -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver2: Discoverability Disabled. Not able to receive connections."
                    )
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTING -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connecting...."
                    )
                    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_CONNECTED -> Log.d(
                        ContentValues.TAG,
                        "mBroadcastReceiver2: Connected."
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: in this code i have problems that i mentioned down below

Comment: E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.digidiv.smartvolume
    getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.digidiv.smartvolume, PID: 21600
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8192KB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `BluetoothClass` instantiates a `BluetoothManagerClass` instance in its init. Your `BluetoothManagerClass` instantiates a `BluetoothClass` in its init. That causes an infinite loop until stack space runs out.

`BluetoothClass` is-a `Activity` and you should not be instantiating activities yourself anyway. Consider e.g. passing your `BluetoothClass` instance reference as a parameter to `BluetoothManagerClass`.